# Can you find the normal vector to the plane by dot product instead of using the cross product?

Tags: plane-geometry

I am trying to calculate the normal vector of a given plane with dot products on the one hand(Attempt 1) and with vector cross products on the other (Attempt 2). The results aren't making any sense to me: shouldn't both attempts which result in orthogonality to vectors in the same plane be similar or related? By both having orthogonal vectors I don't mean orthogonal results. The dot product has a scalar result and the cross product a vector. But I solve for the vector that produces  the scalar result in Attempt 1.

**Points/Vectors Setup:**
*Same plane*, points normalized:
pt1 (-2.562, 571.286, 1)
pt2 (1014.394, 577.530, 1)
pt3 (-4.972, -3.807, 1)
Let $\vec u =~$pt2-pt1 $= ~(1016.956,6.244, 0)$. 
Let $\vec v = $unknown  orthogonal vector for Method 1. 
Let $\vec r = $pt3-pt1 $(-2.41,-575.093, 0)$ 
Let $\vec n =~$unknown orthogonal vector to $\vec u ,\vec v$. 
 
**Attempt 1:  With Dot Product Find $~\vec v~$ Orthogonal to Plane Vector $\vec u$:**
So, 
 $\vec u\cdot \vec v = 0~$ if  $~ \vec u ⟂\vec v $.
Solve for  $\vec v~ $unknown.
$\vec u\cdot \vec v = (u_x,u_y,u_z)\cdot(v_x, v_y, v_z)~$
$~~~~~~~=(u_xv_x+u_yv_y+u_zv_z)$
$\vec u = (u_x, u_y, u_z)$ 
$u_x = 1016.956, u_y =6.244 , u_z = 0$ from points/vectors above
$\vec u\cdot \vec v =(1016.956v_x+6.244v_y+0v_z)$
 
Simplify equation, $v_z$ component = 0:
$\vec u\cdot \vec v =(1016.956v_x+6.244v_y)$
Set $\vec u\cdot \vec v = 0$, our unknown $(\vec v )$will be perpendicular to $\vec u$
Choose values that complete the equation:
Select y = 10, while z = 0 already, leaving $v_x= -6.244(10)/1016.956 =-0$.0614
 $\therefore$ unknown$~\vec v = (-.0614, 10, 0$).
**Attempt 1: Test the Answer:**
Is $\vec v ⟂ \vec u?$
 
if true $\vec v \cdot \vec u = 0$
 
ok, check:
 
$\vec v \cdot \vec u = (1016.956, 6.244, 0)\cdot(-.0614, 10, 0)$ 
$~~~~~~~ =-1.108$
 
$~~~~~~\therefore ~\vec v ⟂ \vec u.$

**Attempt 2: Find $\vec n$ from cross product**

Using two vectors $\vec r, \vec u~$ from the same plane:see(from **Points/Vectors**)
$\vec u × \vec r = \vec n$
 
$\vec u × \vec r = (1016.956, 6.244, 0)×(-2.41,-575.093, 0)$ 
$\vec n = (0,0, -584829.229)$
 
Are the 2 vectors orthogonal?:
 
$\vec n\cdot\vec u = 0$?
 
$(0,0,-584829.229)\cdot (1016.956, 6.24, 0) = 0,~\therefore ~$yes.
check if $\vec n \cdot \vec v = 0$?
 
$(0,0,-584829.229)\cdot (-2.41,-575.093, 0) = 0,~\therefore ~$yes.

Comment: Attempt 1 makes no sense!    The plane consists of all points (x,y,1), so normal has to be a vector (0,0,z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution is incomplete. You’ve found one vector that’s perpendicular to $\vec u$, but it also needs to be perpendicular to $\vec r$. Even with the correct value for $\vec u$, choosing $\vec v$ in the way you did doesn’t produce a vector that’s perpendicular to $\vec r$. You need to solve the *system* of equations $\vec u\cdot\vec v=0$, $\vec r\cdot\vec v=0$.

At the risk of confusing things, there’s another rather direct method available that you didn’t try. The equation of the plane is going to have the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$. If you plug in the coordinates of the three points, you’ll get a system of three linear equations in the unknown coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Solve that system.

Comment: "You need to solve the system of equations". This is the analysis I was looking for. Can you please tell me how to setup the system of equations you mention. Just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @splitinfiinity It’s there in the last sentence. Just expand those dot products.

Comment: UxVx + UyVy+ UzVz = 0 & rxVx + ryVy+rzVz = 0 ?

Comment: Also I am aware of using the vectors of the 3 points and solving for the normal (N) <a,b,c> to the plane. I also know how to get to ax+by+cz + d = 0 from N.P+d = 0 by expanding those dot products.

Comment: My final question is can you find the normal(N) of a plane with equation N.P + d = 0? Or do you have to break it down with vector cross product and revert to the plane equation<a,b,c>.<x-xo, y-yo, z-zo> from ax+by+cz + d =0?

Comment: This is an answer: [Find normal vector without using cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608616/can-you-find-the-normal-vector-to-the-plane-by-dot-product-instead-of-using-the)

Comment: @splitinfiinity If you have follow-up questions, you should post a new question instead of asking in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three points to get three vectors in that plane. Then using dot product you can create 3 equations. Then solving those three equations you will get the vector taht u want

Comment: How do I avoid 3 unknowns?

Comment: This is an answer: [Find normal vector without using cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608616/can-you-find-the-normal-vector-to-the-plane-by-dot-product-instead-of-using-the)